# How To Hide Polygons In Python Tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse

The purpose of my code is to have a triangle replaces a cursor. However, I need a solution to delete the triangles which were drawn previously by previous cursor movements.

This is my original code:

```
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.attributes('-topmost',True)
window = Canvas(width = 1300, height = 700, bg = 'black',\
            highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
window.pack()
window.config(cursor='none')

class Cursor:

    def __init__(self,canvas):

        self.canvas = canvas    
        self.id = self.canvas.create_polygon(0,0,10,0,0,-10)

    def Move(self):

        self.Mousex = self.canvas.winfo_pointerx()
        self.Mousey = self.canvas.winfo_pointery()
        self.id = self.canvas.create_polygon(self.Mousex,self.Mousey,\
                                         self.Mousex+10,self.Mousey,\
                                         self.Mousex,self.Mousey-10,\
                                         fill = 'red')
Cursor1 = Cursor(window)

while 1:
    tk.update_idletasks()
    window.update()
    Cursor1.Move()
```

I have tried the following code, but then no triangles appear at all. In the following code I inserted a:

```
self.canvas.delete(self.id)
```

so that the code is:

```
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.attributes('-topmost',True)
window = Canvas(width = 1300, height = 700, bg = 'black',\
            highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
window.pack()
window.config(cursor='none')

class Cursor:

    def __init__(self,canvas):

        self.canvas = canvas    
        self.id = self.canvas.create_polygon(0,0,10,0,0,-10)

    def Move(self):

        self.Mousex = self.canvas.winfo_pointerx()
        self.Mousey = self.canvas.winfo_pointery()
        self.id = self.canvas.create_polygon(self.Mousex,self.Mousey,\
                                         self.Mousex+10,self.Mousey,\
                                         self.Mousex,self.Mousey-10,\
                                         fill = 'red')
        self.canvas.delete(self.id)

Cursor1 = Cursor(window)

while 1:
    tk.update_idletasks()
    window.update()
    Cursor1.Move()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas already has a [`move`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method) method defined, which you can use instead:

```
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.attributes('-topmost',True)
window = Canvas(width = 1300, height = 700, bg = 'black',\
            highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
window.pack()
window.config(cursor='none')

class Cursor:

    def __init__(self,canvas):

        self.canvas = canvas    
        self.id = self.canvas.create_polygon(0,0,10,0,0,-10, fill='red')
        self.Mousex = 0
        self.Mousey = 0

    def Move(self):

        _new_x = self.canvas.winfo_pointerx()
        _new_y = self.canvas.winfo_pointery()
        self.canvas.move(self.id, _new_x - self.Mousex, _new_y - self.Mousey)
        self.Mousex = _new_x
        self.Mousey = _new_y
        #self.canvas.delete(self.id)

Cursor1 = Cursor(window)

while 1:
    tk.update_idletasks()
    window.update()
    Cursor1.Move()
```